# Play music at the end of function with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to start a music file by passing it to a function and then play it automatically after the another function has completed execution. Once the function finishes I want to play "done.mp3", and on an error play "error.wav" etc...

I just want to write down easy pure JavaScript function to do so. Call it wherever and provide an .mp3, or .wav music file... and it plays it directly.

My work will be used within an ASP.NET project.

I want to be able to work it in Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to multiple of search beside other think I found a solution unfortunately it's not working for IE.
I can just add tool inside div this one works for Firefox, and chrome:

`document.getElementById("TestDiv").innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' ID= 'audioPlayerElement' src=" + MusicLink + " ></audio>";`

Answer (score 1):

Create an Audio element and trigger it from your function like this:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = 'link/to/audio/file.ogg|mp3'; //mp3 not supported in current FF

audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
   audio.play();
}, false);
```

Or pre-load the audio - when you get to the end of your function call `audio.play()`.

```
if (audio.attr('readyState')) audio.play();
```

If no `readyState`, just use a `setTimeout` to re-try. Rememeber to check for errors (in case file does not exist, unsupported codec etc.).

Comment: Thank you, but can you give tell me how can i add link from current project like `src = '../../Done.MP3'` because it doesn't play files in my project? unfortunately I'm new in doing play audio stuff

Comment: I'm using Firefox browser and i want to try work this thing on Firefox, chrome, IE

Comment: @Kero Firefox doesn't support MP3 unfortunately. You would need to convert it to OGG (Vorbis). Chrome does, not sure of IE (they never seem to agree on these things...).

Comment: @Kero As to link it would be impossible for me to know without knowning your file structure for the site. Why not try to put it in root folder for site for testing and then use `/file.ogg` as src. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for support but even i have tried .wav file and doesn't work like `../../../Music.Done.wav `

Comment: thank you for support but even i have tried .wav file and doesn't work like `../../../Music.Done.wav `
There is no need for structure i just put a hyperlink to a song and this one works but in another scenario i want to use my own music files then I'm trying to pass a link from my computer like `../../music/done.wav`

Comment: @Kero ah, so you are trying to load these files directly from somewhere at your harddisk? In that case that won't work. The files must resides in the site's folder structure (for security reasons). You need to copy the files to the root folder of your site (or a sub folder).

Comment: Thank you @Ken, but unfortunately it doesn't work with Firefox but it works for chrome, I wish If you know another way to play files in Firefox...